# Do you have to deallocate NSString *objects after you're done using it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a NSString that can be used to set a text for UITextView:

```
for (int score = 0; score < 100; score++){
   NSString *newScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", score];
   [_scoreText setText:newScore];
}
```

My question is: after the loop is done, will I have 100 objects in memory that I have to deallocate manually, or will ObjectiveC clean the garbage automatically after we leave the scope of the loop?

Comment: How do I check it? I'm using Xcode 4.3.6 and developing for iOS 5+

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380533/how-do-i-know-if-my-program-has-arc-enabled-or-not

Comment: It doesn't really matter in the specific case. See my answer below

Comment: Here's a trivial way to know if you project is using ARC or not - try adding a call to `release` on some object. If you get errors about it not being supported under ARC then you are using ARC. If no error then you are using MRC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Both with and without ARC `stringWithFormat:` will return an autoreleased object.

So all the `NSString` instanced created with the loop will be deallocated at some point after the loop execution (i.e. when the autorelease pool is drained).

Anyway if you are creating many autoreleased objects inside the loop, you may want to wrap the loop body inside an `@autoreleasepool` block, so that the strings are released at every iteration

```
for (int score = 0; score < 100; score++){
   @autoreleasepool {
       NSString *newScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", score];
       [_scoreText setText:newScore];
   }
}
```

This can significantly increase the performance of your loop, in case of **many** iterations.

Comment: Gabriele, is @autoreleasepool allowed under ARC?

Comment: @zaitsman. Yes, `@autoreleasepool` blocks are supported both by ARC and MRC environments.

Comment: Also, even in MRC they should be preferred to the previous `NSAutoreleasePool` approach, as **much** faster.

Comment: I think the @autoreleasepool should be outside the for loop

Comment: No it shouldn't be. That would defeat the entire point of having it.

Comment: @CiNN Catfish already answered. Placing it outside the loop is roughly equivalent to not having it at all.

Comment: I was just thinking that for 1 string having the autoreleasepool inside the loop puts more strain than outside